# endDate showing as Invalid Date using Daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am using the daterangepicker to select the startDate and endDate. As the startDate works fine but the endDate shows as Invalid Date.

Here is my code:

```
var dateformat = "D MMM YYYY";

var displayDate = function() {
            var dateformat = "D MMM YYYY";
            var begin = moment($("#add-start-date").val());
            var end = moment($("#add-end-date").val());

            if( begin !== null && end !== null ) {
                $("#add-start-date").parent().removeClass("hidden");
                $("#add-start-date").parent().siblings().removeClass("hidden");
            } else if( begin !== null ) {
                $("#add-start-date").parent().removeClass("hidden");
                $("#add-start-date").parent().siblings().addClass("hidden");
            }

            if (begin !== null){
                $("#add-start-date").html(begin.format(dateformat));
            }
            if (end !== null){
                $("#add-end-date").html(end.format(dateformat));
            }

            $("#add-when-results").removeClass("hidden");
            // $(".facet-when h5").hide();

            if( begin === null && end === null) {
                $("#add-when-results").addClass("hidden");
                $(".facet-when h5").show();
            }
        };
$(function(){

    $(".facet-when").daterangepicker({
        format: dateformat,
        locale: {
            fromLabel: 'From',
            toLabel: 'To'
        },
        parentEl: "#mem-add-overlay .facet-when"
        },
        function(start, end) {
            var begin_string = "";
            var end_string = "";
            if( start !== null ) {
                begin_string = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            }
            if( end !== null ) {
                end_string = end.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            }
            $("#add-start-date").val(begin_string);
            if( begin_string === end_string  ) {
                $("#add-end-date").val("");

            } else {
                $("#add-end-date").val(end_string);
            }
            displayDate();
        });
});
```

Html line:

```
<input id="id_add-when" maxlength="100" name="add-when" type="hidden">
```

When clicking the input field, it opens the calendar. The startDate will be the current day date and the endDate will be the same. If I directly click the apply button, the startDate takes fine but endDate returns the InvalidDate. Again If I select the endDate then the endDate takes fine..

Any suggessions please

Comment: can you add a JSFiddle to your post??

Comment: What daterangepicker plugin do you use? The problem will be solved faster if you provide working example here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Yashwanth: Facing the same issue. Did you find any fix for that?

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp Not yet. I left it on that day to complete some other tasks. I am working on it right now. Will update it ASAP for you. If you get the solution please update the answer.

Comment: @Yashwanth: I got the solution in meantime: You should following date format which will work on all the browsers: 2015-09-02T04:41:16

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp Okay. Can You update the sample working code. I have tried in that way too. But no result with me.

Comment: @Yashwanth: You should use this date format while passing date to datepicker: 2015-09-02T04:41:16. It will work in all the browsers.